# Почему в Wordpress не применяются стили в меню от Bootstap?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

Пытаюсь сделать динамическое меню на вордпрессе, на основе темы. В wp_nav_menu в container_class и menu_class проставляю тот же класс, что у меню в верстке navbar-nav ml-auto, но по стилям получается дичь. Почему не применяются стили?

сам сайт tempest.beget.tech
видео https://yadi.sk/i/NF5iKuepQB13vQ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]